# How to move specified columns to the end of its DataFrame without changing the order of all other columns?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of columns spread throughout a DataFrame. Those columns have one thing in common, which is that their column names all contain "___" in them. How do I move all of these columns to the end of the DataFrame?

e.g. aaa___1, abc_2___2, xyzhw1___3 ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `contains` to select specified columns

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c(3,4),a__2=c(1,2),col2=c(5,6))
df

  col1 a__2 col2
1    3    1    5
2    4    2    6

cbind(select(df,-contains("__")),select(df,contains("__")))
  col1 col2 a__2
1    3    5    1
2    4    6    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `order` and `grepl`

```
dat[order(grepl("___", colnames(dat)))]
  A B aaa___1 abc_2___2 xyzhw1___3
1 3 5       1         2          4
2 4 6       2         3          5
3 5 7       3         4          6
4 6 8       4         5          7
```

##### data

```
dat <- structure(list(aaa___1 = 1:4, abc_2___2 = 2:5, A = 3:6, 
xyzhw1___3 = 4:7, B = 5:8), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```